# ASP.NET: Session expired after folder delete

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having code where i am moving files to another folder and deleting previous folders and files in an ASP.NET application. After deleting folder, my session is expired. How can I restrict to expire session values.

Comment: Please do not close this question. Possibly this needs an edit.

Comment: So, could you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Very true. This happens because deletion make changes to the folder tree of the ASP.NET application and this forces the application to recycle. See here: http://www.geekays.net/post/2008/10/14/ASPNET-webdomain-recycle-on-subfolder-changes.aspx

Comment: but how can i avoid to expire session values

Comment: Please read the topic and avoid deleting folder inside the ASP.NET app. The topic discusses different options and should help you arriving at a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code inside Global.asax page

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p = typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
    object o = p.GetValue(null, null);
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo f = o.GetType().GetField("_dirMonSubdirs", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
    object monitor = f.GetValue(o);
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo m = monitor.GetType().GetMethod("StopMonitoring", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    m.Invoke(monitor, new object[] { }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Write your Directory deletion code within Session_End method in globle.asax

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SampleDelete();
}
private static void SampleDelete()
{
    try
    {
        string samplesss = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\temp";
        string[] array1 = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(samplesss);
        try
        {
            foreach (string item in array1)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.Delete(item, true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```